# Flutter compute method work fine in debug mode but not in release or profile

Tags: flutter, dart-isolates

It's wearied that how the compute method works smooth in debug but freeze the UI in profile and release.

I uploaded a project to test the issue you [GitHub Link](https://github.com/7mada123/flutter_compute_test)

As I know dart JIT and AOT should behave the same!.

I tested it on different android devices and windows as well, I also tried using isolate and changing the extension method to normal function but no luck.

[GitHub issue Link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88063).